Problem loading extended information for MusicItem in user library
Helo!
I tried to load additional info such as recordLabels, releaseDate, url, editorialNotes, copyright for music items in user library but this properties always nil.
Here is the code i used to load albums from user library:
func getLibraryAlbums() async throws -> MusicItemCollection<Album> {
    let request = MusicLibraryRequest<Album>()
    let response = try await request.response()
    let albums = response.items
    return albums
}

Here is the code i used to load extended info:
func loadExtendedInfo(for album: Album) async throws -> Album {
    let album = try await album.with(.tracks, .audioVariants, .recordLabels, preferredSource: .library)
    if album.title.contains("Christm") {
        printJsonRepresentation(for: album)
    }
    return album
}

According to the documentation

because the tracks relationship for an Album is supported in both the library and the catalog, and because the this code specifically requests MusicPropertySource.library as the preferred source, the framework will load the tracks from the user’s library. However, because the recordLabels and relatedAlbums associations are only available in the Apple Music catalog, the framework will also issue a network request to Apple Music API to fetch those associations of content from the catalog.

however, the requested properties, with the exception of the track property, are always nil.
Please tell me, am I doing something wrong or is this a MusicKitt bug?
P.S. My app get permission for music data according to documentation and hase authorisation status authorized.
